# Estimation of velocity of the wave from seismic trace

Tags: seismology, seismic

How can seismologists estimate velocity (on the different layers) of the wave propogated through the earth , only from given seismic trace(s) ?

Comment: Well, technically you can't do anything with what you've listed here (other than analyze the spectral characteristics of the trace). At the very least, data such as offset, estimated location of epicenter+focus, and time are required. Perhaps that's what you're getting at, but I'd suggest refining the details of the question more!